# Up Navigation Confirmation

Tags: java, android

I have a score keeping application in which the parent activity allows the user to enter custom team names.

[image]

The user can then keep score during a game.

[image]

Should the user hit the back button while in the score keeping activity (to return to the team selector activity), I've implemented a confirmation due to a loss of the scoring data:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Return to team selector")
            .setMessage("Returning to the team selector will reset the scores. Are you sure " +
                    "you want to continue?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

I'd like to implement a similar confirmation when the the user "up navigates" to the parent (i.e., the team selector) since there will be the same loss of scoring data. However, I've run into problems doing so.

Is there an analogous "`onUpPressed`" function I'm failing to find? Any other guidance on how I might solve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: If you are in fragment you have to call `getActivity().onBackPressed();`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `onUpPressed` method in android. You need to write it in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method and handle it there.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Return to team selector")
                .setMessage("Returning to the team selector will reset the scores. Are you sure " +
                        "you want to continue?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                        return true;
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Override`  this method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
           // do your stuff here for Upnavigation
             onBackPressed();
        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```